# generate-sources phase from containing project is broken

Tags: spring, maven, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I have a project that defines a module in its pom.xml:

```
<modules>
    <module>mytestmodule</module>
</modules>
```

The module uses `spring-boot-starter-parent` as its parent. Additionnally, the module uses in its pom.xml the plugin `jooq.codegen-maven` to generate source files from a database:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <jdbc>
                    <driver>xxx</driver>
                    <url>xxx</url>
                    <user>xxx</user>
                    <password>xxx</password>
                </jdbc>
                <generator>
                    <target>
                        <packageName>org.jooq.schema</packageName>
                        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                    </target>
                </generator>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I run the `generate-sources` phase from the module directory, it correctly generates the source files in a schema directory. However, when I run the command from the containing project (the parent directory), not only does it not generate the source files, but it also **deletes** them. How to fix this?

Comment: What's the jOOQ version you're using?

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.0 so the inferred jOOQ version should be 3.14.4 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jooq/2.4.0)

Comment: I checked with `mvnw dependency:tree` and the jOOQ version is 3.14.3.